# Adding layers using ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, feature-layer

I am right now adding individual layers using `FeatureLayer` but it takes quite some time to load as the map is for US Counties (3076 count). I tried to load it using `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` but I was not successful. It seems that `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` can load mapserver but not the layers in the mapserver.

I used the following code but it did not work.

```
var ftrLyr = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url, {
    visibleLayers: [1]
});
```

Is it not possible to load layers in a mapserver using `DynamicMapService`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter visibleLayers isn't an option used in the construction of an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer. What you can do is call the setVisibleLayers method on the layer before adding it to the map. Here's an example using your example:

```
var ftrLyr = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url);

ftrLyr.setVisibleLayers([1]);

map.addLayer(ftrLyr);
```

Comment: i swear I tried this and it was not working before but now it is!! Thanks

Comment: Are the url which you are using for feature layer and ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer are the same...???

Comment: Almost @Gunner. Except for the last `mapservice/1` for `featureLayer` everything else is same for `DynamicLayer`